# Connection Error In Grails

Tags: grails

I am getting the Following error while running grail App. I have tried all sort of things but the error doesn't go away .

Can anyone please help.

```
`Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-mysql-connector-java/tags/RELEASE_5_1_16/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.pom`
```

**MY Config.groovy**

// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config
// config files can either be Java properties files or ConfigSlurper scripts

```
// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) 
   {
//   
     grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]

// }
grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination
grails.mime.file.extensions = true // enables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format
grails.mime.use.accept.header = false
grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
                      xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
                      text: 'text/plain',
                      js: 'text/javascript',
                      rss: 'application/rss+xml',
                      atom: 'application/atom+xml',
                      css: 'text/css',
                      csv: 'text/csv',
                      all: '*/*',
                      json: ['application/json','text/json'],
                      form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
                    ]

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']


// The default codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// enable Sitemesh preprocessing of GSP pages
grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// enable query caching by default
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = true

// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
    // appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}

// Added by the Mahout Recommender plugin:
mahout.recommender.mode = 'config'  // 'input', 'config' or 'class'
mahout.recommender.hasPreference = true
mahout.recommender.selected = 1 // 1. user-based, 2. item-based or 3. slope-one
mahout.recommender.similarity = 'PearsonCorrelation' //'PearsonCorrelation', 'EuclideanDistance', 'LogLikelihood' or 'TanimotoCoefficient'
mahout.recommender.withWeighting = false
mahout.recommender.neighborhood = 2
mahout.recommender.data.model = 'mysql'
mahout.recommender.preference.table = 'preference'
mahout.recommender.preference.valueColumn = 'pref_value'

mahout.recommender.hasPreference = false
mahout.recommender.data.file = 'ratings.dat'
export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -server"
```

Comment: may be something wrong with dependency in your BuildConfig.groovy 

do you use mysql database?

Comment: I am trying to run the project downloaded from git.

Comment: And it uses MySql in code

Comment: can you post git repository, or your BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: https://github.com/rbramley/GroovyMagMahout

Comment: I am trying to follow this blog : http://leanjavaengineering.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/grails-mahout-recommenders/

Comment: I just clone repository and it's work fine. (Grails 2.2.0, JDK 6 Ubuntu 12.04)  
do you modified some code?

Answer (score 1):

please check your `"grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy"`

I think you may accidentally edit its. look like msql-connector was place in wrong place.

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'  // RIGHT PLACE
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    //runtime ':mysql-connector-java:5.1.16' // WRONG PLACE, IF YOU SAW HERE.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found that the I needed to set the proxy for grails

Comment: Can u please tell how can I Downgrade/uninstall Grail. I have downloaded the newer version and the application is built for older version.

Comment: why down grade? you can run "grails upgrade" to upgrade your project to match your Grails version.

Comment: If you want to use multi version of Grails. I suggess https://github.com/gvmtool/gvm